# Why NativeBase is so static?

Tags: react-native, stylesheet, styling, native-base

Don't misunderstand me. NativeBase is fantastic, but it's feels horrible to change the easiest things... Like when I just want an Icon to wrapped inside  a View, then for some reason my Icon will receive a top and bottom margin, and I can't override it :/.

Or when I just tried to put 2 buttons inside a footer. When I wanted to give padding to the Footer component the buttons got pushed down. Native Base is fantastic, but if you want something what not out of the box then the simplest thing can get overwhelming...

```
<View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <View style={{ borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, alignContent: 'center' }}>
        <Icon style={{ fontSize: 50, height: 'auto'}} name='camera'/>
    </View>
</View>
```

Am I the one who can't use NativeBase properly, or it is really that hard to make little things work?

Comment: I've had the same experience. Overriding styles can be a pain. I think it's usually easiest to make your own components unless you need something fairly complex which already exists.

Comment: I would recommend to check NativeBase customizer and then reply here http://nativebase.io/customizer/

Comment: Unfortunately the customizer just van help to over ride the default style. My problem with NativeBase is how static when I move it out of it comfort zone: like an icon inside a view.

Comment: But yet, this customiser is really, really nice! :)

Comment: @IstvanOrban Nothing like comfort zone, everything works fine.
Do check docs for use cases